# What properties does a custom cck_phone form field need to work?

Tags: 7, entities

I am struggling to get a working custom implementation of a cck_phone field from the [cck_phone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/phone). I have included my partially working code at the bottom.

What seems to be not working is that the function `cck_phone_phone_number_process` expects to be able to retrieve information about the widget with

`$instance = field_widget_instance($element, $form_state);
$settings = $instance['settings'];`

However in my implementation, `field_widget_instance($element, $form_state)` returns NULL, resulting in both `$instance` and `$settings` being NULL and problems further on in the `cck_phone_phone_number_process` function.

What does work is that the code below does render a properly populated country code dropdown and phone number entry textfield.

My code to create the custom cck_phone field:

```
$form_section['phone']['field_phone_home'] = array(
    '#type' => 'phone_number',
    '#field_parents' => array(
        'profile_personal_information'
    ),
    '#field_name' => 'field_phone_home',
    '#language' => 'und',
    '#delta' => 0,
);
```

Comment: cck_phone does define a form element (good) but uses field functions (bad), have you tried to file an issue on drupal.org? by custom implementation I assume you mean a custom form which is not an entity form with fields on it?

Comment: I have filed an issue on Drupal.org. I have received no help from that issue. I guess I don't fully understand the second part of your comment - _"by custom implementation I assume you mean a custom form which is not an entity form with fields on it?"_ By "custom form" I mean it is a form built in code using various fields from various parts of user profiles, not a built in form to a module, or part of webform or something like that.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant, the form is not an entity form (even a custom entity type) -> thus field hooks wont be called -> probably you have no luck and should to patch the module!

Comment: The phone field works fine elsewhere, rendering an extension field, etc. I find it hard to believe that it works elsewhere perfect, but cannot work here...can you support your supposition with evidence?

Comment: Can you give me an example of it working elsewhere, somewhere which is not an entity creation/editing form?
maybe I can figure it out what's wrong

Comment: If you add it to a user's profile it works fine.

Comment: Users and their profile *are* entities, and their form are entity forms, thus field hooks are invoked. anywhere else?

Comment: It works any place you add it as a field via the UI...I assume none of those apply and are all entities and I am totally screwed then...

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find an exact answer to this question, but I was able to find a work around to get the extensions to load.

using form_alter, after the field is partially built in a form function

```
//set value for office extension
  if(
    isset($form_state['storage']['$profiles']['personal_information']->field_phone_office[LANGUAGE_NONE])
    &&
    $form_state['storage']['$profiles']['personal_information']->field_phone_office[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['extension'] != NULL
  ){
    $field_phone_office_ext_value = $form_state['storage']['$profiles']['personal_information']->field_phone_office[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['extension'];
  }
  else{
    $field_phone_office_ext_value = '';
  }

  $form['user-information']['user-information-fieldset']['profile']['phone']['field_phone_office']['extension'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Ext.'),
    '#default_value' => $field_phone_office_ext_value,
    '#value' => $field_phone_office_ext_value,
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'phone-extension'
      )
    )
  );
```